# Magento extension not showing up in back-end

Tags: magento-1.9, module, extensions, plugin, third-party-module

### What is wrong?

Recently I tried out an extension on my test environment of magento 1.9.2 It was a succesful installation with magento connect.

The extension worked perfectly.

so I tried it out on my real environment but the extension / module doesn't work and won't show up in my modules tab ( system - configuration - advanced ). so I can't enable or disable it.

the files have been places in the right folder ( app - code - community ) So far I tried

reinstalling the extension
logging in and out
flushing the cache
re-indexing the website
But sadly it did not seem to work on my real environment.

### What extension?

this is about the "Catalog Search Refinement FREE" extension.

The extension has no panel since all this extension does is change the way magento searches for products.

I am new to magento, so I might not know much and I've read a lot but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: check files permissions of the uploaded extension, make sure you uploaded files not only into app/code/community, but also in app/etc/modules

Comment: If Compiler Status is Enabled, Go to `System > Tools > Compilation` and click on `Run Compilation Process`.

Comment: I have yet to learn about permissions, could you explain me how to check and change the permissions?

I looked into the folder you told and the XML file was indeed in there, the codepool was correct and it was set as active as it should.

Comment: thanks! @babyInMagento , okay but I'm still stuck with my case, even after running the compilation process it didn't fix my problem.

Comment: @babyinMagento Exactly, it is only showing that it's installed in magento connect but not in the modules tab

Comment: @JeffreyUllers check these links once : [link1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/installed-magento-extension-is-not-showing-in-admin-panel) , [link2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6476/magento-custom-module-is-showing-in-advanced-tab-but-not-showing-in-admin-config) , [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331727/magento-extension-is-installed-in-backend-but-not-visible-on-frontend) , [link4](https://www.web2market.com/magento-extension-not-showing-in-admin/)

Comment: I checked all of those out and I tried everything but sadly it did not solve it.. I think there's something blocking my extension somewhere altho it might be the core since previous software engineers have edited the core files, is there a way I can overwrite this?

Comment: @JeffreyUllers you can take backup of all core files and than copy the fresh magento [ same version]  , than copy the core files....

Comment: @JeffreyUllers i didt got notification for your  previous comment, so 
check [link](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/970/list-of-standard-comments-for-review/1048#1048)

Comment: @BabyInMagento I had to wait untill this morning to try that since it's a live webshop. sadly this didn't quite work out. I swapped the {sitename}/app folder but that caused an error which totally broke down my website lol.  even after deleting the maintenance.flag I kept getting the 503.php in front of me ( plus I couldn't enter the back-end, which is logical since the core files were swapped ).

Comment: @JeffreyUllers you can replace the backup files & try contact extension developers once......

Comment: @babyInMagento I am working on that, it takes a while to transfer the files tho. oh and the funny thing is, they aren't here anymore. they were trainee's who quit a while ago, they edited the core files which is why I am trying to repair this. since I need to make a fully functional website out of it.

Comment: @JeffreyUllers is `test environment` is same as `real environment` ? also if possible try disabling other extensions/modules with help of app/etc/modules folder.... make sure you take backup of that `modules` folder before doing any changes.....

Comment: @BabyInMagento yeah it is, what I didn't think about was the differences in database usernames and passwords, I am still checking the logs for further issue's, sadly I don't understand much of it yet.  I need the modules tho

Comment: @JeffreyUllers i thought there may be chances that another module override this module , so its not working, but as you said both `test & real` environment are same, than mostly disabling other modules may not work...

Comment: @BabyInMagento that would be strange since the test website also has the same modules, why would it work in 1 and not the other? that's what is bothering me xd

Comment: @BabyInMagento I was wondering, is there any way I can swap the 2 websites? I am hosting both websites via shockmedia, the only thing that's different between these two is that the name, username and password of the database is different. but these are configurable I think. anyway, do you know of a way to swap them?

Comment: @JeffreyUllers you can take backup of real site files and database & than copy the `test site` files to real site .... download the test site database file and open the database file with editor software like `notepad++` than replace the test domain name with the real domain name and than save the file & assign that database to live site..... make sure you take backup of both site files & db before doing any changes.....

Comment: @JeffreyUllers you will get more details here : [link](https://www.google.co.in/search?dcr=0&source=hp&q=transfer+magento+from+one+domain+to+another&oq=magento+transfer+one+doma&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i22i30k1.1234.6568.0.8292.27.18.0.0.0.0.691.3580.0j7j5j1j0j1.14.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..13.14.3574.0..0j35i39k1j0i131k1j0i22i10i30k1.0.Osx5EKT3yms)

Comment: @JeffreyUllers did you got any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So okay I found out Magento wasn't deleting my cache properly, after hours and hours of searching for errors, editing lines of code it was simply running on my cache all the time. 
Even after flushing the cache and reindexing my website countless times I wondered if my cache was being deleted correctly. 
Since I kept getting the same advice from other people to flush my cache I wondered if it was being flushed correctly. so I went to `var/cache` and saw that even after flushing my cache these files remained.

So I deleted all the folders in `var/cache` and logged out and in on my Magento back-end and I noticed directly that the extension was working as it should.